# Contrast color of line with background (FabricJS & HTML5 Canvas)

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, fabricjs

I am using FabricJS and I need to contrast the color of a dashed line depending on the background.
Example: For the same dashed line, if the background is white, the line is blue, if the background is blue, the line is white.

The canvas background color could change but with a white one, i could add a blue rectangle and add a divider (dashed line) over the whole canvas.

Answer (score 1):

**Different answers depending on your background**

*Do you know the background color?*

**If yes**, just code up some conditional dash colors based on the known background color.

**If no**, you can get the pixel RGBA color at a dash point using `var a = context.getImageData(dashX,dashY,1,1).data` and set an appropriately contrasting dash color. You will get a 4-element array with the pixels red, green, blue & alpha values.

*Another possible problem*

The problem comes if your background is not mono-colored -- F.ex., an image. Then you might have to do light+dark dashes. You can do that by specifying a white dash with a black shadow (shadow having 2px blur because 1px blur is often jagged).

Here's example code and a Demo showing how to draw dual-colored dashed lines:

[image]

```js
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
var cw=canvas.width;
var ch=canvas.height;

ctx.lineWidth=3;
ctx.setLineDash([15, 5]);

ctx.fillStyle='black';
ctx.fillRect(0,0,cw,ch/2);
ctx.fillStyle='white';
ctx.fillRect(0,ch/2,cw,ch/2);

dualDashline(0,50,300,50);
dualDashline(0,250,300,250);
dualDashline(0,75,300,200);

function dualDashline(x0,y0,x1,y1){
  ctx.shadowColor='white';
  ctx.shadowBlur=2;
  ctx.strokeStyle='black';
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(x0,y0);
  ctx.lineTo(x1,y1);
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.stroke();
}
```

```css
body{ background-color: ivory; padding:10px;}
#canvas{border:1px solid red; margin:0 auto; }
```

```html
<h4>Dual colored dashed lines</h4>
<canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
```

Comment: Thank you for tou answer. The user chooses the color of background and could differenciate some areas. According to other technologies bringing a solution to this problem, if i could know how, i will use the background lightness to determine the color of a current pixel.
The background could be not mono-colored but i will be rare and should be treated as a mono-colored for the area of the image.
But when there is a real light contrast (as blue and white), the dash pixel color should change.

Comment: I understand how to exploit the ImageData but not how to apply another color to the dashed line, have you any solution ?

Comment: @Loenix: I've added example code to my answer. Good luck with your project!

Comment: Il like this solution but i don't know if this will be pretty on paper and if my client will accept it. Thank you for your help, you bring me a good solution. To change the color of the dash line while rendering, i probably need to write a complete rendering function for each pixel ?